# How can I add aspx and aspx.cs files to newly created solution? and get the .csproj files?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in ASP.NET. I have three .aspx file and their associated .aspx.cs files in a folder. These three screens are parts of the project that I can run them in browser.

1. How can I get the project files (.csproj) from aspx and aspx.cs files?
2. how can I group these three aspx and aspx.cs files under one solution in Visual Studio? Basically, I need the solution file of the project but I have just aspx and aspx.cs files. I created a web application in VS 2013 for web, but when I'm clicking the **add existing item** to the newly created solution, both options (***new website*** and ***existing website***) are inactive. why I can't add aspx and aspx.cs files under a new solution?

Comment: It might help to understand that solutions are really containers, and what they contain is projects. Your .asp* files will go inside of a project. This is really super foundational stuff. You might consider checking out Pluralsight if you're struggling.

Also, don't go with websites, that's deprecated and that's probably why it's unavailable. What you want is probably a web application project.

Comment: awesome, it worked. I had to create empty web application not website. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, I suppose I will write that up as an actual answer, so this doesn't just end up with comments.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to understand that Solutions are really containers, and what they contain is Projects. Your .asp* files will go inside of a project.

Also, WebSites are deprecated (or you might be looking at Azure WebSites which is probably not what you want). Either way, you probably need to create a Web Application Project.